# renaming a fat16 volume

Tags: windows, partition, fat

What's the easiest way to rename (change the volume label of) a fat16 volume (e.g. on a USB drive) from linux?  It seems like `mlabel` from the `mtools` package is meant to do this, but the documentation is not geared to rapid assimilation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `sudo mlabel -i <device> ::<label>`, for example `sudo mlabel -i /dev/sdb1 ::new_label`.

Reference: [RenameUSBDrive on the Ubuntu community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RenameUSBDrive#FAT16%20and%20FAT32).

Comment: Thanks.  Figured this one myself, and answered with a bit more info at my [cross-post](http://superuser.com/questions/223527/renaming-a-fat16-volume/223530#223530)